# Check child process's status in a parent C systems programming ( without using SIGSTOP ) - POSIX

Tags: c, operating-system, posix, systems-programming

I want to write a program that uses only SIGUSR1/SIGUSR2 signals for pausing and resuming a multiple number of child processes that work on a same problem simultaneously. If I use a signal handler to send an info that a child process has paused of course when its multiples are sent they will merge into one. Since I am using sigsuspend, is there a way to know when at least the last process finished so that i don't signal a parent before the last child finishes. Also, if that is not possible is it possible to somehow find out that child process is suspended by checking some of those 3 files made when a process is created. Thanks in advance!

Comment: `If I use a signal handler to send an info that a child process has paused of course when its multiples are sent they will merge into one.` You are referring to sending the info in a signal from the child to the parent?

Comment: You'll have better luck with SysV IPC `msgsnd/msgrcv`. You should post your code in a code block here.

Comment: @Zoso Yes of course, I am sending it as kill( getppid(), SIGUSR1 ). That's how i programmed it. It can be checked if the process is terminated of course using waitpid for example but that wouldn't work for pausing except if i use SIGSTOP which i don't want to do. I want to somehow simulate SIGSTOP let's say